# Change constraintlayout according to List

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have a row of buttons I want to rearrange according to a value coming from sharedpreferences. The value is changed and listened to correctly, but still nothing happens in the layout, so the mistake must be somewhere in the class I use to set the list or in the fragment where I set the constraints. This is the class:

```
class ButtonPosLists(context: Context) {

var mContext: Context = context

val view = inflate(mContext, R.layout.fragment_level, null)
val dobutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.dobutton)
val dirabutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.dirabutton)
val rebutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.rebutton)
val rimebutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.rimebutton)
val mibutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.mibutton)
val fabutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.fabutton)
val fisebutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.fisebutton)
val sobutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.sobutton)
val silebutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.silebutton)
val labutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.labutton)
val litabutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.litabutton)
val tibutton = view.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.tibutton)

val c = listOf(dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton)
val db = listOf(dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton)
val d = listOf(rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton)
val eb = listOf(rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton)
val e = listOf(mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton)
val f = listOf(fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton)
val gb = listOf(fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton)
val g = listOf(sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton)
val ab = listOf(silebutton, labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton)
val a = listOf(labutton, litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton)
val bb = listOf(litabutton, tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton)
val b = listOf(tibutton, dobutton, dirabutton, rebutton, rimebutton, mibutton, fabutton, fisebutton, sobutton, silebutton, labutton, litabutton)

var posList = bb

fun makePosition(posString: String?) {
when(posString) {
    "c" -> {
        posList = c
    }
    "db" -> {
        posList = db
    }
    "d" -> {
        posList = d
    }
    "eb" -> {
        posList = eb
    }
    "e" -> {
        posList = e
    }
    "f" -> {
        posList = f
    }
    "gb" -> {
        posList = gb
    }
    "g" -> {
        posList = g
    }
    "ab" -> {
        posList = ab
    }
    "a" -> {
        posList = a
    }
    "bb" -> {
        posList = bb
    }
    "b" -> {
        posList = b
    }
}
println(posList[7].toString())
}
}
```

And in the fragment I want to apply those lists to, I use this:

```
fun setPositions() {
    val params = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[0].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params1 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[1].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params2 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[2].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params3 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[3].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params4 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[4].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params5 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[5].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params6 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[6].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params7 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[7].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params8 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[8].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params9 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[9].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params10 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[10].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    val params11 = FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[11].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams

    params.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params.endToStart = guideline1.id
    params.startToStart = container.id
    params.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[0].requestLayout()

    params1.topToTop = guideline9.id
    params1.endToStart = guideline13.id
    params1.startToStart = guideline12.id
    params1.bottomToTop = guideline8.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[1].requestLayout()

    params2.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params2.endToStart = guideline2.id
    params2.startToStart = guideline1.id
    params2.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[2].requestLayout()

    params3.topToTop = guideline9.id
    params3.endToStart = guideline14.id
    params3.startToStart = guideline13.id
    params3.bottomToTop = guideline8.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[3].requestLayout()

    params4.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params4.endToStart = guideline3.id
    params4.startToStart = guideline2.id
    params4.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[4].requestLayout()

    params5.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params5.endToStart = guideline4.id
    params5.startToStart = guideline3.id
    params5.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[5].requestLayout()

    params6.topToTop = guideline9.id
    params6.endToStart = guideline16.id
    params6.startToStart = guideline15.id
    params6.bottomToTop = guideline8.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[6].requestLayout()

    params7.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params7.endToStart = guideline5.id
    params7.startToStart = guideline4.id
    params7.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[7].requestLayout()

    params8.topToTop = guideline9.id
    params8.endToStart = guideline17.id
    params8.startToStart = guideline16.id
    params8.bottomToTop = guideline8.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[8].requestLayout()

    params9.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params9.endToStart = guideline6.id
    params9.startToStart = guideline5.id
    params9.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[9].requestLayout()

    params10.topToTop = guideline9.id
    params10.endToStart = guideline18.id
    params10.startToStart = guideline17.id
    params10.bottomToTop = guideline8.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[10].requestLayout()

    params11.topToTop = guideline8.id
    params11.endToEnd = container.id
    params11.startToStart = guideline6.id
    params11.bottomToTop = guideline7.id
    FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.posList[11].requestLayout()
}
```

Any idea where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet) instead of [`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams). According the the documentation of `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`. (*Italics* are mine.)

> This class contains the different attributes specifying how a view want to be laid out inside a ConstraintLayout. *For building up constraints at run time, using ConstraintSet is recommended.*

Answer (score 1):

You are changing your layout attributes after inflating them, further changes will not automatically apply on the existing layout. Try to use [invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) to trigger onDraw method of your top layout, after applying new layout parameters.

Comment: I tried adding `FullscreenActivity.buttonPos.view.invalidate()` in various places (like at the end of `setPositions()`, right after calling `setPositions()` in my fragment´s `onResume()`), but it had no effect.

Comment: Anyway, I decided to go for `ConstraintSet` now, and it works, but thanks nonetheless.